# underscore iteration javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, underscore.js

I'm trying to create an object using underscore and backbone. I currently have an array of objects which inside have a record with another object and sets of data.

data[0] contains the name of the location while
data[2] contains the coordinates for that location

```
data: Array[3] 0: Objectcol_id: "4" data: "W Hotel Union 
Square" __proto__: Object1: Object2: Objectcol_id: "13"data: "40.736638, -73.988396"
```

To get the coordinates and push them to a new array I'm using the following function:

```
var newarr  = _.map( rawData, function ( a ) { return [a.records[0].data[2].data] });
```

I then split the array of coordinates and create an object with key value pairs where I set the coordinates.

```
var newnewarr = [];

for (i = 0; i < newarr.length; i++) {
  newnewarr[i] = _.map(newarr[i][0].split(","), function(s){ return parseFloat(s);
  });
}

function longlat( lat, long) {
  this.Latitude = lat; this.Longitude = long;
};

var coordinates = [];

for (i = 0; i < newnewarr.length; i++) {
  coordinates[i] = new longlat(newnewarr[i][0], newnewarr[i][1]);
  }
```

What I'm trying to do now but I'm having a hard time is trying to create an object that looks like the following:

```
newarr = [ {
   latitude: 40.736638,
   longitude: -73.988396,
   title: "W hotel Union Square"
   },
 {
   latitude: 40.736638,
   longitude: -73.988396,
   title: "Union Square Park"
   },
```

My question is how to a create this array of objects using what I have? I tried starting by iterating over the data object but I'm having a hard time doing it. Where it says data[2], id like to iterate over data[0, 2] to obtain those values and then push them to an object. Hope this is clear!

```
var newarr  = _.map( rawData, function ( a ) { return  [a.records[0].data[2].data] });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily with a second _.map() call, like this:

```
var rawData = [<your raw data here>];

var tempDataArray = _.map( rawData, function ( a ) { return [a.records[0]] });

var finalDataArr = tempDataArray.map(function(d) {
    var tempCoordinatesArray = d[2].data.split(",");

    return {
        latitude: tempCoordinatesArray[0],  
        longitude: tempCoordinatesArray[1],
        title: d[0],
    }
});

console.log(finalDataArr);
```

Or if you want to do it in one step:

```
var rawData = [<your raw data here>];

var finalDataArr = rawData.map(function(d) {
    var tempData = d.records[0];
    var tempCoordinatesArray = tempData[2].date.split(",");

    return {
        latitude: tempCoordinatesArray[0],  
        longitude: tempCoordinatesArray[1],
        title: tempData[0],
    }
});

console.log(finalDataArr);
```

P.S. Try picking better names for your arrays!

Comment: Thank you so much!! will definitely work on my array naming conventions. This worked perfectly.. :)